# Store installed mono version into variable inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, script

I am working on some Linux appliction installation script. This app requires [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) to be installed for its successfull installation. So, inside `bash` installation script I run `mono --version` and check the output of it:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.8.0 (Stable 4.8.0.371/902b4a9 Tue Feb  7 00:58:05 CET 2017)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       normal
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  ppc
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        GC:            sgen
```

If `mono` is installed, I get upper text as result and how do I now do following tasks (inside `bash` script):

1. Store `4.8.0` string (from *Mono JIT compiler version 4.8.0)* into variable
2. Convert `4.8.0` **string into** `480` **as unsigned long** so I can compare versions inside this `bash script`?

Answer (score 0):

I've succeeded with piping `mono --version` output text to `awk`:

```
mono --version | awk '/version/ { print $5 }'
```